# Query CosmosDb using CosmosClient with a custom serializer

Tags: c#, azure-functions, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to query CosmosDB using CosmosClient with a custom serializer inside an Azure Function.

This is my custom serializer:

```
public class CosmosDbSerializerService : CosmosSerializer
{
    private readonly JsonSerializer jsonSerializer;

    public CosmosDbSerializerService()
    {
        jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer
            .Create(JsonSerializerFactory.GetJsonSerializerSettings());
    }

    public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new(stream))
        using (JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new(streamReader))
        {
            return jsonSerializer
                .Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
        }
    }

    public override Stream ToStream<T>(T input)
    {
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new())
        using (JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new(stringWriter))
        {
            jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, input, input.GetType());
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringWriter.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code where I setup the `CosmosClient` using DI:

```
builder.Register(_ =>
{
    CosmosClientBuilder cosmosClientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(productionDatabaseSettings.ConnectionString)
        .WithCustomSerializer(new CosmosDbSerializerService())
        .WithHttpClientFactory(() =>
        {
            HttpMessageHandler httpMessageHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
            };

            return new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler);
        })
        .WithConnectionModeGateway();

    return cosmosClientBuilder.Build();
});
```

If I run the code and call the function with Postman I get a 200 OK, but no results are returned. I checked the query string using the online tool Data Explorer, and it works as expected.

What I noticed, and I'm not able to explain why, is that if I follow the running code in Visual Studio, after executing `CosmosDbSerializerService.FromStream`, the execution jumps to the object `CosmosJsonSerializerWrapper` implemented by Microsoft ([here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Serializer/CosmosJsonSerializerWrapper.cs)) into the method:

```
public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
{
    T item = this.InternalJsonSerializer.FromStream<T>(stream);
    if (stream.CanRead)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Json Serializer left an open stream.");
    }

    return item;
}
```

that throws the exception.

No idea how to solve it, and a question: why, if I setup my `CosmosSerializer`, the code still uses `CosmosJsonSerializerWrapper`?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's an uncommon thing to have to do, but in this instance, you have to dispose the stream. Which is what the error message is trying to tell you.

```
public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
{
    // Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client requires JsonSerializer to close the stream.
    using (stream) //<--- here
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new(stream))
    using (JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new(streamReader))
    {
        return jsonSerializer
            .Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could just call `Dispose()`